# Select count for each distinct row (mysql and php)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am using mysql and php.

I have a table with one column.  I can show unique rows by:

```
select distinct id from id_table
```

This might show

```
1
2
3
5
```

What I want to do is show the number of 1's, 2's, etc there are.

I could do

```
select count(id) from id_table where id = 1
```

But then I have to run a query for every... single... row... And with hundreds of thousands of rows, not good.

Is there a way to return an array of the counts of each distinct item

Data

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5
```

Results

```
3, 1, 2, 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
select id, count(id)
from table
group by id
```

If only want count of ids, then

```
select count(id)
from table
group by id
```

Here is a simple tutorial of group by clause

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp