# Count number of unique values

Tags: mysql

If I have three columns:

```
orderNumber, name, email
```

and I would like to count how many unique emails are in the table how would I go about doing so?

A statement like:

```
SELECT count(email) FROM orders
```

gives me the total count.

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT count(email) FROM orders`

but that does not seem to be giving me the numbers I am expecting.

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264658/select-count-for-each-distinct-row-mysql-and-php

Answer (score 156, accepted):

use

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT(email) ) FROM orders
```

Distinct provide unique email ids and then simply count them.

Comment: As much as I appreciate an answer, could you explain why this is different from what I was doing for my own edification?

Comment: that way you're counting distinct emails, not distincting email count

Comment: @thatidiotguy, by doing "SELECT DISTINCT count(email) FROM orders" you are counting all email first (including duplicates) and then filtering using distinct. so you will receive total number of email not total number of distinct emails.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya : I upvoted you, I was answering thatidiotguy :-)

Comment: @AlpeshGediya : me netiher, and actually I think I'm being very creative with English on that one :-)

Comment: I have a unique key in place, however the query is still very heavy on my 25 million rows database. Any suggestions for making it faster?

Comment: @PaulBGD: check the execution plan, DISTINCT probably uses disk (whatever index you have), and that will be slow.

Comment: shows zero for me (but there are a lot of records in db)

Comment: @AlexeySh. please share your query.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT  count(DISTINCT(email)) FROM orders
```

its different from your posting, since its filters out the duplicates before counting it

Answer (score 7):

The accepted soultion doesn't work for me - it returns a "1" for each unique email address in the table.

This is what I had to do to get the info I needed:

```
select email, count(email) AS total from sysAccessLog group by email order by total desc
```

Which returns a list of email addresses and the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance you should use:

```
SELECT 
sub.email, 
count(1) as 'count_unique' 
FROM 
(SELECT email FROM orders GROUP by email) sub
```