# Getting count of unique column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Could some one help me out with an Sql query where I can retrieve the count of all the customers name present in each city .

You can find the example table here [Link to the table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Basically I want to get a result where we come know how many customer names are present in each city

Please let me know if you need any other details

Comment: Can you add the excpected result?

Comment: Use GROUP BY and COUNT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Count Number of Unique Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697215/mysql-count-number-of-unique-values)

Comment: Both are different questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT City, COUNT(CustomerID) as CustomersPerCity
FROM Customers
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: Perfect . never thought of using group by clause :) Thank you

Comment: Does that matter? (At least as long as you don't do count(distinct name).)