# Find unique users grouped by month - sql

Tags: sql

I have the following table and I'd like to find the total number of unique users who have triggered **only** event 'B' for example. And then group it by months.

**Table**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it stands, this feels a bit like asking to solve a homework question. You might want to detail what you've already tried, and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Count Number of Unique Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697215/mysql-count-number-of-unique-values)

Comment: Check the dupe and add a `where` and `group by`

Comment: Hi guys, no these are not homework - I just simplified my question and extracted the gist out of it in order to ease on the people who might answer.

Comment: pdpi - I've tried left join, I've tried cases. the former didn't work since it was too heavy for the server to process and was running for more than an hour (until I stopped it) and the latter just couldn't assure "only b" situation, but included "b and a" and "b and c" situations inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the users who have only ever triggered B you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.event = 'B'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                                          AND t2.event <> 'B');
```

I'm not sure what you mean with "And then group it by months.". Maybe the count per month?

```
SELECT t1.month,
       count(*)
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.event = 'B'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                                          AND t2.event <> 'B')
       GROUP BY t1.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
SELECT MONTH, COUNT(USER_ID)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE EVENT = 'B'
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH
```

Comment: thx but this is to simple and cannot assure that the users weren't in the other events.